# .NET Core 2 app builds but publishing fails

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I get the following error when I build a .net core 2 console.
I just want to create a .exe that I can run on windows server.

here is the error I get

```
project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0/win10-x64'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. You may also need to include 'win10-x64' in your project's RuntimeIdentifiers.
```

Here is my csproj content

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

<PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
  <SccProjectName>SAK</SccProjectName>
  <SccProvider>SAK</SccProvider>
  <SccAuxPath>SAK</SccAuxPath>
  <SccLocalPath>SAK</SccLocalPath>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>win10-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>    
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Telegram.Bot" Version="13.2.1" />
</ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: `project.assets.json` is generated automatically by restore. Did you try clearing out your `obj` and `bin` folders and building again?

Comment: I have, if i use dotnet restore -r win10-x64 and dotnet publish -c Release -r win10-x64 then it works, i think the error might be with visual studio itself, also how do i just target .net framework 4.6.2 instead of .net core, as the server I have  already has the framework and rather use that then the core

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem using  'dotnet restore; dotnet build; dotnet publish'

Comment: it works fine with cli commands, visual studio seems to be the problem

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the comments above that it seems to be an issue with VS. I had a similar issue: I unloaded the problem project, reloaded it, and all was well.